How to Isolate a Reactive Expression in R Shiny They Reevaluate When Switching Navigation Tabs
I have created the following reactive expression to accumulate data from a Master file in a R Shiny app. This reactive expression is called accumulatedData() and it is located in 1 of the 4 navigation pages. For reference, let's call the tab where is located A. And the other 3 tabs let's call them B, C and D.
Whenever I am in A, accumulatedData() works well and gets updated as it is supposed. However, whenever I switch to other of the 3 tabs and come back to tab A, accumulatedData() seems to get reevaluated. Additionally, it only stores the last submission made by input$submitBtn2. Does anyone know why this is the case?
I tried to solve it with isolate() but it didn't work. Thank you so much in advance for all the help.
The code I am referring to is below:
# Initialize reactiveValues object to store the list of data tables
      accumulatedData <- reactiveVal(list())
      
      # Filter and append the all the selected FSAs
      isolate(
        observeEvent(input$submitBtn2, {
          if (!is.null(selected_FSA2()) && selected_FSA2() != "") {
            newTable <- selected_data2()  # Get the current selected data
          
            # Generate a unique identifier for this submission using timestamp
            uniqueID <- paste0(selected_FSA2(), "_", Sys.time())
          
            # Retrieve the current list, append the new table with the unique ID, and update the reactiveVal
            currentData <- accumulatedData()
            currentData[[uniqueID]] <- newTable
            accumulatedData(currentData)
          }
        
        })
      )

I tried making accumulatedData() not to reevaluate or change unless I click the submitBtn2 in 3 ways:

Using req()
Using isolate()
Changing accumulatedData to be a list and not a reactive expression

The first two filter appropriately the data, but they don't solve the problem exposed before. The accumulatedData() expression reevaluates when changing tabs and only shows the last submission made the last time we were in the tab.
The third doesn't accumulate the data appropriately.
